# Record ID for lightning:fileUpload on Create New Record VF Page

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to use the [lightning:fileUpload](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_fileUpload.htm) component on a Create New Record Visual Force page. The `recordId` of the record the file should be attached to is mandatory.

Is there another way **besides** inserting the record and querying its recordId to upload files to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lightning:fileUpload` won't work for VisualForce Pages. I guess you are using it in a lightning component?

The answer is yes and no, you can't upload attachments, without attaching them to anything.
You could use a temporary record in the background and re-attach it when you are done. But this is not a good way, since the user could always leave the page without saving and you would still have the temporary record in your system.

Comment: Yes, using a lightning app with a lightning component to add it to the VF page.
I'll add some autosave to my apex logic then so that I can grab a salesforce id to use for the data upload. Thanks for confirming!